# how to retrive the latest reading

Tags: sql

```
DATA                RESULT      
A           B        C       A          B        C
REC1    21/02/2019  50      REC1    21/02/2019  50
REC1    20/02/2019  500     REC2    21/02/2019  89
REC2    21/02/2019  89              
REC2    20/02/2019  5000
```

Hi, tried the top 1 * with order by B desc but it just returns 1 record.. How to obtain the two records as shown as RESULT ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which database you are using? Also show us the SQL you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()` which is supported by most dbms

```
   select * from 
   ( select *,row_number() over(partition by A order by B desc) rn
     from table_name 
   ) a where rn=1
```

or you can use corelated subquery

```
  select t1.* from table_name t1
  where t1.B=( select max(B) from table_name t2 where t1.A=t2.A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `a` and join to the main table:

```
select t.* from (
  select a, max(b) maxb
  from tablename
  group by a
) g inner join tablename t
on t.a = g.a and t.b = g.maxb
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5iSvhmenNo4PjXZC9r7TGo/0)